# What is the topology on $O(3,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups

I've read that there are four connected components of $O(3,1)$.

Then, if I'm not mistaken, if $A \in O(3,1)$, then to determine which connected component $A$ is in we look at whether $\text{det}(A)= \pm 1$ and look at the sign of the first entry of $A$ is either greater than or equal or less than or equal to 1.

My question is what topology is given to $O(3,1)$ such that these are the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real $n \times n$ matrices $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ form a normed vector space. (Take the operator norm or view a matrix as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and take the usual norm there.) For finite-dimensional spaces all norms are equivalent and so they induce the same topology. Thus an open set in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a union of open balls with respect to the metric $d(A,B) = \|A-B\|$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is any norm. The topology on $O(p,q) \subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ ($p+q = n$) is just the subspace topology.

Comment: Does the fact that $O(3,1)$ is disconnected then follow from the norm you choose on $O(3,1)$? Or do you use the fact that the determinant is a continuous map between $O(3,1)$ and the set $\{-1,1 \}$ and since $\{-1,1 \}$ is disconnected then so is $O(3,1)$?

Comment: @user1058860 The latter. Using the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, one easily sees that $\det:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Therefore the restriction to the subspace $O(p,q)$, $\det:O(p,q) \to \mathbb{R}$ is also continuous, and $\det(O(p,q)) = \{\pm1 \}$ is disconnected. This shows that $O(p,q)$ has at least two connected components. If I recall correctly, it is then a bit more work to use the fact that an element of $O(p,q)$ preserves the metric of signature $(p,q)$ to show that the time-reversal component splits up each of these components in two.